# jQuery replace href attribute in mouseup function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a plugin that displays a tooltip over a selected Text. This is working fine but i also want that the selected text gets inserted in an a href tag. When i implement it the tooltip doesn't work anymore. here is my code so far. the full JS file and can be found [here](https://github.com/phippuuuu/selection-share)

```js
    $('.holder').mousedown(function() {
      return false;
    });

    $('.holder').mousedown({
        sel = window.getSelection(); 
        selText = sel.toString();
        $("a[href='http://www.uniqueUrlForSelectionShareTwitter.com']").attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(selText.trim()))
    });
```

The js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fmtcwrwb/5/

Comment: So, you want to change a link's `href` when the person clicks on it?

Comment: I wan't to change a link's href with a dynamic generated url from the text the user selected. Finally I wan't a simple twitter share link that shares the selected text @IsmaelMiguel

Comment: You're missing the `function() {}` wrapper from the `mousedown()` and a ')' at the end of `attr()`

Comment: @Zoltan thank's, I didn't notice that i forgott a ). The problem is that when the code is executed, the tooltip placing and displaying doesn't work anymore

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fmtcwrwb/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'click'` event fires **before** the `href` redirection is executed, so you can do:

```
$('your-seletor').click(function(){
  $('your-a-element').attr('href', 'http://new-url-goes-here.com')
                     .click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but the link dosn't work when you click on it. new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmtcwrwb/6/